# Newly created user is not stored in database in Liferay

Tags: java, authentication, liferay

When I create a new user using a custom portlet, I meet a problem: the user is not stored in the `USER_` table in `lportal` database.

I use the standard Liferay user creation method,

```
user = UserLocalServiceUtil.addUser(lots_of_params)
```

Then, when I try to log in with that user, I can't. It seems that `LoginUtil.login(params)` only works if the user is found as a field in the users table.

Why is that and how can I persist my user to the database? I am using Liferay 5.2.3.

Comment: did you call update method? if not try this UserLocalServiceUtil.update(user);

Comment: Converting it to answer so it may help any on else

Comment: If you don't mind mark it as answer so that others can refer this without any hesitation. Of coarse if this answer helps you to resolve your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Add User try this code

```
UserLocalServiceUtil.update(user);
```

HTH